# Should I freeze the svn:externals in the development branch?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have a project with the following structure versioned with SVN:

```
-MyProject
    -src
    -libs
    -extenals
    -docs
```

The externals is a set of folders with libraries of my company added with the svn:externals properties

I want to decide when to update to new changes in the externals, I don't want to these folders to update even if I select all the folders and by error click "Update" in the VC.

I want to start working with a two-branches model a **`Production/trunk`**  branch and a **`Development`** branch, basically working in the development one and merging the changes with the releases (I have not yet created the development branch yet)

About the svn:externals:

1. Should them be frozen in the Development branch?
2. Should them be frozen in the Production branch?
3. If the externals in the production branch should be frozen, how can I freeze them (the branch already exists)

Answer (score 1):

If

> I want to decide when to update to new changes in the externals

you **must** to use PEG-ged revisions in **all** trees, without choice